# Generating a random character out of any two in Java

Tags: java, random, range, character

How do I generate a random character between two specific characters? For e.g; I want to generate either one of 'h' or 'v'.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you used the Random class yet? It has a nextBoolean method that could work well for you.

Comment: Please be more specific or give an example.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: why the snarky comment with the unnecessary *"What have you tried?"*  SO is a place to find answer and I'm beginning to get a bit pissed off by people like you always comment-whoring by saying *"What have you tried?"*.  If you think that *Random* + *nextBoolean* makes an answer, then go on, help the OP, help the SO community, take the time to write the answer that *alexbrn* wrote (and got +5 upvotes for it) instead of comment-rushing-whoring your *"What have you tried?"*.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: if I want to know how to generate a random character out of any two in Java and I, use, say, Google to find about it, then I don't care for neither what the OP tried nor for your *"What have you tried?"* comment.   I care for npinti or alexbrn's **answers**.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: I'm sorry that you find the statement "what have you tried" to be snarky, but it certainly wasn't meant that way. My own experience as a coder is that I learn more if I try something, anything, first before asking for help, and my experience as an instructor has been that I know a lot more about the student's wrong assumptions by first inspecting what they've tried. This can guide me towards a more intelligent and useful answer. Also, I posted more than a simple "what have you tried" in my original comment, and included suggestions for look up.  YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a character, as you say, either h or v, you can generate a random number using the [Random](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class as shown [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62). If for instance the random number is greater than 0.5, then choose v, if otherwise, choose h.

On the other hand, if you have a range of letters, you can either generate an array with the characters you want and generate a random number which will be used as an index to choose the random letter, or else, you can generate random number between 65 (Aschii for A) and 90 (Aschii for Z). You can find more Aschii characters [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, then, kindly click on the 'very good' mark :)

Answer (score 8):

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = r.nextBoolean() ? 'v' : 'h';
```

N.B. construct your Random object once and re-use it; don't re-construct it every time you want a random number!

Comment: I would avoid the ternary operator. It might be confusing for people who do not know a lot about Java yet.

Comment: @Ishtar: people who don't know a lot about neither Java nor C nor C++ nor C# nor all the other languages supporting the ternary operator should better start learning about it...  And this answer is so clean and simple that it is a **very** good starting point to learn how the ternary operator works.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
import java.util.Random;


....

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
char chosen = randomInt % 2 == 0 ? 'h' : 'v';
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random character between two given characters you could do the following:

```
   char genRandChar(char char1, char char2)
    {
       char retVal;

       int val1= (int) char1; //cast char1 to its integer ASCII value
       int val2= (int) char2; //cast char2 to its integer ASCII value

       //assuming val1<val2
       retVal=(char)(val1+(int)(Math.random()*((val2-val1)+1)); //generate a random number between val1 and val2 and cast it to a character
       return retVal;
    }
```